# Rails Javascript not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a portfolio website that consists of mostly static pages, I am trying to create an effect where the site runs seemlessly as one page (from the home page to the main page), and as such as I need to use Javascript/Jquery.

For some reason, my format.js code does not get executed when I link_to from one static page to another. Here is my code

NavigationController

```
def home

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js       
    format.html 
  end

end

def main
end
```

and in the view (**home.html.erb**) I have

```
<%= link_to navigation_main_path, remote: true do %>
<h2> ENTER SITE </h2>
<% end %>
```

and **routes.rb**

```
get 'navigation/home'
get 'navigation/main'

root to: 'navigation#home'
```

My **format.js.erb** for testing purposes, which is located in **app/views/navigation** is

```
alert('hi');
```

I can not figure this out at all and would appreciate any help.

Comment: For you request the main action.Put format codes inside your main action.

Comment: but the view/controller action is home?

Comment: Understand that <%= link_to navigation_main_path, remote: true do %>, Visit this path will excute js format in your main action. not your home action.

Comment: Moving the code to the main action still doesn't fix the problem and the js doesnt run

Comment: Show your js codes and where you write it.

Comment: i have updated the code with my javascript

Comment: Rename format.js.erb to main.js.erb. your code will work.

Comment: Thanks Xiao!, the code in main.js.erb runs now but the link is not navigating to my main.html.erb and stays on home.html.erb still. Should I just do that in the Jquery?

Comment: If you want the link work. In main.js.erb file, add codes:    window.location.href="<%= navigation_main_path %>"

Answer (score 0):

in your code try with format option

```
<%= link_to navigation_main_path(format: :js), remote: true do %>
```